# COUNT counting something on LEFT JOIN that doesn't exist. Why?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having a problem.

I have this table called `usersbycourse` which shows this information:

```
+------------+-----------------+--------+-----------+-------+-----------------+-----------------+
| instanceid | shortname       | userid | firstname | logid | lastaccessdelta | modulesfinished |
+------------+-----------------+--------+-----------+-------+-----------------+-----------------+
|          2 | PJU             |     74 | Robin     |   766 |         1662246 |               0 |
|          3 | Fundgest-GRHN1A |     75 | Batman    |   867 |         1576725 |               0 |
|          3 | Fundgest-GRHN1A |     77 | Abigobeu  |  1004 |          610480 |               0 |
+------------+-----------------+--------+-----------+-------+-----------------+-----------------+
```

and this SQL:

```
SELECT
mdl_course.id,
mdl_course.shortname,
COUNT(CASE WHEN usersbycourse.modulesfinished = 1 THEN NULL ELSE 1 END) AS studentcount
FROM mdl_course LEFT JOIN usersbycourse ON mdl_course.id = usersbycourse.instanceid
GROUP BY mdl_course.id;
```

The results from the SQL are:

```
+----+-----------------+--------------+
| id | shortname       | studentcount |
+----+-----------------+--------------+
|  1 | Unity I         |            1 |
|  2 | PJU             |            1 |
|  3 | Fundgest-GRHN1A |            2 |
|  4 | asdzxc2         |            1 |
+----+-----------------+--------------+
```

But why? In inside SQL has no Unity I, and no asdzxc2. How do I produce a result like this:

```
+----+-----------------+--------------+
| id | shortname       | studentcount |
+----+-----------------+--------------+
|  1 | Unity I         |            0 |
|  2 | PJU             |            1 |
|  3 | Fundgest-GRHN1A |            2 |
|  4 | asdzxc2         |            0 |
+----+-----------------+--------------+
```

?

EDIT:

I want to count only rows having modulesfinished = 0

Comment: if you want count `modulesfinished = 0` why your condition is `modulesfinished = 1` ?

Comment: that's because when modulesfinished = 1, i won't count the row.

Comment: `count <> 1` is different to `count == 0` You should try `COUNT(CASE WHEN usersbycourse.modulesfinished = 0 THEN 1 END) as studentcount`

Comment: You're right. It's really the best option. I didn't know about this difference on COUNT. Thanks!

Comment: Wait a bit, I see what is the real problem and will write and answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is `SUM` rather than `COUNT`, that is,

```
SELECT
mdl_course.id,
mdl_course.shortname,
SUM(CASE WHEN usersbycourse.modulesfinished = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS studentcount
FROM mdl_course LEFT JOIN usersbycourse ON mdl_course.id = usersbycourse.instanceid
GROUP BY mdl_course.id;
```

Comment: I tried this answer but it produced the same result

Comment: I've adjusted my answer based on your question edit.

Comment: Whoa! It works! But... Why
"CASE WHEN usersbycourse.modulesfinished = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END" is different from "CASE WHEN usersbycourse.modulesfinished = 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END"?

Comment: It's likely because you are using a `LEFT JOIN` and there are rows in `mdl_course` which don't join to any in `usersbycourse`.

Comment: @wogsland Check my answer. This answer is correct, but you need to understand why.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because you are using `LEFT JOIN` some of the values for `usersbycourse.modulesfinished` are `NULL`

Something you need to learn is

```
  NULL == something
```

Is always `unknown`, not `true`, not `false`, just `unknown`.

So when you try to compare with `= 1` your nulls get the `ELSE` but not because they aren't 1, is because is all the rest.

So if instead you change the condition to

```
COUNT(CASE WHEN usersbycourse.modulesfinished = 0 THEN 1 ELSE NULL)
```

Only the `TRUE` match will get 1, the `FALSE` and the `UNKNOW` part ill get `NULL` and `COUNT` doesnt count nulls. And that is what you want.